# Not sure why i cant print the cost in line 112. it says

Tags: c

when I run it says:

`incompatible pointer to integer conversion passing int (int, int) to the parameter of type char [-Wint-conversion]`

I am unsure how to fix this because it requires a char value to determine the "if" statements any and all help is appreciated.

// this program takes time parked and time left (in military time) and a character (C,B,T) to determine the parking fee.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

// ---------------------func calc minutes parked -----------------------//

int total_minute_parked (int minute_in, int minute_left)
{
  int minute_parked;
  if (minute_left > minute_in)
    {
      minute_parked = abs((minute_left + 60) - minute_in);
    }
    else 
      {
        minute_parked = abs(minute_left - minute_in);
      }
 return minute_parked;     
}

// ---------------func calc total hours parked ----------------------//

int total_hour_parked (int hour_in, int hour_left)
{
  int hours_parked;
  if (hour_left > hour_in)
    {
      hours_parked = abs((hour_left - 1) - hour_in);
    }  
    else 
      {
        hours_parked = abs(hour_left - hour_in);
      }
return hours_parked ;
}

// funtion to calc charge based off type of vehicle 

float amount_charged (char vehicle_type,int total_hour_parked)
{
char C;
char T;
char B;

  float temp_charged;
if  (vehicle_type == C) // ------------------------------------CAR 
  {
    if (total_hour_parked > 3) 
    {
      float secondary_hour = total_hour_parked - 3;
      temp_charged = secondary_hour * 1.5;
    }
    else 
        {
          temp_charged = 0;
        }
  } 

else if  (vehicle_type == T)   // -----------------------------TRUCK 
  {
    if (total_hour_parked > 2) 
    {
      float secondary_hour = total_hour_parked - 2;
      temp_charged = (secondary_hour * 2.3) + 1;
    }
    else {
          temp_charged = 1;
        }
  } 

else if  (vehicle_type == B) // --------------------------------BUS 
  {
    if (total_hour_parked > 1) 
    {
      float secondary_hour = total_hour_parked - 1;
      temp_charged = (secondary_hour * 3.7) + 2;
    }
    else {
          temp_charged = 2;
        }
  } 
return temp_charged;
}

// main that prints results and takes imput
```

// ------------------------results printed in main -------------------------//

```
int main() 

{

  int total_hour_parked (int hour_in,int hour_left);

char vehicle_type;
int hour_in = 0;
int minute_in = 0;

int hour_left = 0;
int minute_left = 0;

printf("Please enter the type of Vehicle:"); scanf("%c",&vehicle_type); 

printf("Please enter the hour entered lot:"); scanf("%d", &hour_in);

printf("Please enter the minute entered lot:"); scanf("%d", &minute_in);

printf("Please enter the hour left lot:"); scanf("%d", &hour_left);

printf("Please enter the minute left lot:"); scanf("%d", &minute_left);

printf("Parking time: %d:%d\n", total_hour_parked(hour_in,hour_left),total_minute_parked(minute_in,minute_left));

printf("Cost %f",amount_charged(total_hour_parked,vehicle_type));
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should help identify which line 122 is. This is a lot of code to review.

Comment: `amount_charged(total_hour_parked,vehicle_type));` should be `amount_charged(vehicle_type, total_hour_parked));`

Answer (score 1):

Your parameters are in the wrong place.  Your function

```
float amount_charged (char vehicle_type,int total_hour_parked)
```

but when you print it out

```
printf("Cost %f",amount_charged(total_hour_parked(hour_in,hour_left),vehicle_type));
```

Comment: now it displays "main.c: In function 'main':
main.c:112:46: warning: passing argument 2 of 'amount_charged' makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
 printf("Cost %f",amount_charged(vehicle_type,total_hour_parked));
                                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~"

Comment: @RebornxAngel_ Sorry I didn't realize `total_hour_parked` is a function and not an integer.